# Error when migrating contracts using truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

When using traffle deploying contracts it gives these errors:

```
"Migrations" -- Unable to decode sender address from transaction: 
Incompatible EIP155-based V 38 and chain id 3. 
See the Common parameter of the Transaction constructor to set the chain id....
```

And my `truffle-config.js` like this:

```
 networks: {
development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
  port: 9545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
  //gas: 8e6,
  //gasPrice: 20,
  network_id: "5777",       // Any network (default: none)
},

ropsten: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
    privateKeys: [testnetPrivateKey],
    providerOrUrl: `https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ropstenAlchemyApiKey}`
  }),
  network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000000,
  gas: 4000000,
  confirmations: 1,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  timeoutBlocks: 50000,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```

What does these errors mean and how should I configure to prevent that failure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When constructing HDWalletProvider pass `chainId: 3` can solve the problem.

```
  ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
      privateKeys: [testnetPrivateKey],
      providerOrUrl: `https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ropstenAlchemyApiKey}`,
       ////////////////////////////
      chainId: 3 // add this
```

}),

Comment: Cool, that worked. Had to use `chainId:4` in my case since using rinkeby. Have no idea why it works though, so if someone can chime in to explain, that would be appreciated :D.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [chainid-vs-networkid](https://medium.com/@pedrouid/chainid-vs-networkid-how-do-they-differ-on-ethereum-eec2ed41635b) for more details about `chaindId`